# I've a doubt regarding Environment Model of execution

Tags: programming-practices, programming-languages, generic-programming

I came across Environment Diagrams,it is described below

> Whenever Python needs to work with an object, that object is stored in
> memory; and, additionally, Python also needs a way to associate names
> with the objects it has stored in memory. And so there will be two
> important categories of things for us to keep track of in our
> diagrams: we'll need to keep track of the objects that are in play,
> and we'll also need to keep track of the names that we can use to
> refer to those objects.

My question is,
***a) Can we use the Environment Model of execution in other languages like C,C++,Java ?
b) Is the Environment Model a language independent concept ?***

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the concept of an “environment” is a language independent concept. The term is used frequently in programming language theory, though “bindings” is more generic: names are “bound to” something, for example a value or a type. Bindings may or may not be mutable, so this concept is also meaningful in functional languages.

Many language implementations have a compilation phase during which bindings are handled. Then, variable names are replaced by an offset in a table, which allows for faster lookups at runtime. The name of variables is then only retained in debug information. This strategy is used by most C/C++ compilers, but also by Python's CPython reference implementation. The data structure containing the values of local variables in a function is usually called a “frame” or “stack frame”.

Python is a very dynamic language. You can inspect and manipulate the current environment through the `locals()` and `globals()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

This can be used with higher level languages where language takes care of memory management. It might be a bit different with lower level languages like C, C++ because you are given access to memory addresses. Also this model may not be useful in functional languages where language doesn't allow mutations of values (you want to mutate, create new value).